# Is it possible to make background of activity layout transparent in kotlin android

Tags: android, background, kotlin, transparent

I downloaded code of github repo: https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar which is written in `kotlin` android, In that project my requirement is to make background of one of my activity transparent, but still I failed to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `Kotlin`. Just add this line to your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

For more details and other properties of your need, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700683/1820644) answer.

Comment: I tried  but its not working for me , showing white background each time . then i created java class in same project for testing purpose tranparent layout of java class is working properly ... its only not working in kt classes